# How to create comma separated string value if key matches in dictionary<string, string>?

Tags: c#

I have a `string[]` as below. Basically, this contains a set of filters and I want to separate them with a key. Key can be duplicate and if this happens then add comma separated value.

What is the best approach to that? Is any other alternative to `Dictionary`? If there is, then I am open for it.

**Input:**

```
var input = new List<string>
{
    "Location=COL&StockNumber=1111150416",
    "Location=NYC&StockNumber=2222250416&Invoice=Part",
    "Location=NYC&StockNumber=2222250416&Invoice=Part&Supplier=AutoZone"
};
```

**Expected Output:**

```
var output = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Location", "(COL, NYC)" },
    { "StockNumber", "(1111150416, 2222250416, 2222250417)" },
    { "Invoice", "(Part)" },
    { "Supplier", "(AutoZone)" }
};
```

*Issues*

- If key already exists, then throws an error. Want to add bracket and comma separated value.

**Code:**

```
var testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for(var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++) {
    var items = keys[i].Split("&");

    for (var j = 0; j < items.Length; j++)
    {
        var data = items[j].Split("=");
        if (testDictionary.ContainsKey(data[0]))
         {
            testDictionary[data[0]] = // ADD Comma separated value here but not sure how to do that.
         }
        testDictionary.Add(data[0], data[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *Linq* query:

Given

```
var input = new List<string> {
   "Location=COL&StockNumber=1111150416",
   "Location=NYC&StockNumber=2222250416&Invoice=Part",
   "Location=NYC&StockNumber=2222250416&Invoice=Part&Supplier=AutoZone"
};
```

We can get the required dictionary as ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tRcMqt))

```
using System.Linq;

...

var output = input
  .SelectMany(line => line.Split('&'))
  .Select(item => item.Split('='))
  .GroupBy(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1])
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
                group => $"({string.Join(",", group.Distinct())})");
```

What's going on:

1. We split each string by `&` and flatten the enumeration. Now we have enumeration of `"Key=Value"` strings
2. We split each `"Key=Value"` by `=` into an arrays `pair`
3. We *group* by `pair[0]` (which will be Key) `pair[1]`s which will be values
4. We `Join` `Distinct` values for each Key
5. Finally, we materialize the result as `Dictionary`

Comment: dumb question. I will be using this as query params. Since I am getting `(COL, NYC)` here and SQL expects `('COL', 'NYC')`, would that be an issue?

Comment: GThree: you can try chaning the last line from `group => $"({string.Join(",", group.Distinct())})");` into `group => $"({string.Join(",", group.Distinct().Select(item => item.All(c => char.IsDigit(c)) ? item : "'" + item.Replace("'", "''") + "'"))})");`. I've edited the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect values to `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` to store unique values for the keys and then transform `HashSet<string>` to a comma separated string:

```
var input = new List<string>
{
    "Location=COL&StockNumber=1111150416",
    "Location=NYC&StockNumber=2222250416&Invoice=Part",
    "Location=NYC&StockNumber=2222250416&Invoice=Part&Supplier=AutoZone"
};

var testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
foreach (var key in input)
{
    var items = key.Split("&");

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var data = item.Split("=");
        if (!testDictionary.ContainsKey(data[0]))
        {
            testDictionary[data[0]] = new HashSet<string>();
        }
        testDictionary[data[0]].Add(data[1]);
    }
}

var output = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var entry in testDictionary)
{
    output[entry.Key] = $"({string.Join(", ", entry.Value)})";
}
```

Also there is a way to make it without intermediate values with single LINQ query. First we need to split all strings to `{key, value}` pairs then group it by keys and give a distinct values for each group:

```
var output = input
    .Select(key => key.Split("&"))
    .SelectMany(items => items, (items, item) => item.Split("="))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1])
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => $"({string.Join(", ", group.Distinct())})");
```